# What's mean this error on RNN implementation?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I got bellow error, what does it mean and how to fix?

```
<ipython-input-205-0168dbb1480c> in hidden_layer(batch_size, input_data)
      2 
      3     cell= tf.contrib.rnn.RNNCell(1)
----> 4     state = cell.zero_state(batch_size=batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)
      5 
      6     with tf.variable_scope("RNN"):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py in zero_state(self, batch_size, dtype)
    283     # Try to use the last cached zero_state. This is done to avoid recreating
    284     # zeros, especially when eager execution is enabled.
--> 285     state_size = self.state_size
    286     is_eager = context.executing_eagerly()
    287     if is_eager and hasattr(self, "_last_zero_state"):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py in state_size(self)
    254     or TensorShapes.
    255     """
--> 256     raise NotImplementedError("Abstract method")
    257 
    258   @property

NotImplementedError: Abstract method
```

the code that gave the error is the following:

```
def hidden_layer(batch_size, input_data): 
      cell= tf.contrib.rnn.RNNCell(1) state = cell.zero_state(batch_size=batch_size, dtype=tf.float32) 
      with tf.variable_scope("RNN"): 
          tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables() 
          output_cell, status = cell(fl[0], state) 
          input_data = input_data.append(output_cell) 
          fcl = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected( ...omit... ) 
      return fcl
```

Comment: could you share the code responsible for the mistake please?

Comment: def hidden_layer(batch_size, input_data):
    cell= tf.contrib.rnn.RNNCell(1)
    state = cell.zero_state(batch_size=batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)
    with tf.variable_scope("RNN"):
        tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
        output_cell, status = cell(fl[0], state)
    input_data = input_data.append(output_cell)
    fcl = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
        ...omit...
    )
    
    return fcl

Comment: You have to provide us with a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That means we need to know what value `batch_size` holds. And by the way, `input_data = input_data.append(output_cell)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: `RNNCell` is an abstract base class, serving as a basis for various RNN implementations such as simple RNNs, LSTMs, GRUs etc. You are likely looking for `tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNN`.

Comment: xdurch0 probably has your answer. The error message is pretty clear `raise NotImplementedError("Abstract method")`. You are using the wrong class, `RNNCell` is an abstract class, which should be used as a base class for some inherited class. The inherited class will implement this method. If you need deeper insight, look google object oriented inheritance and/or polymorphism.

Comment: @xdurch0 thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: @EMil_Vatai thanks, 